# How to prove that $(\mathbb{Z}, d)$ with $d(m,n)=\vert m -n \vert$ is complete

Tags: metric-spaces

I know that the metric space $(X,d)$ is called *complete* if each Cauchy sequence is convergent, but I don't now how to prove the following:

$(\mathbb{Z}, d)$ with $d(m,n)=\vert m -n \vert$ is complete.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I'm a little confused. You have a hypothesis with no conclusion; do you just want to prove that $(\mathbb{Z},d)$ with $d(m,n)=|m-n|$ is complete?

Comment: yes I did to prove that

Comment: Every discrete space is metrizable and complete under any metric giving the discrete topology.

Answer (score 4):

If $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequences in $(\Bbb Z,d)$, then take $\epsilon<1$. There is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_k-x_l|<ϵ$ for $k,l>m$. So how can $x_k$ and $x_l$ be related?

On the other hand, if you know that closed subspaces of complete spaces are complete, and that $(\Bbb R,d)$ is complete, then it suffices to show the closedness of $\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but your answer if you can give me the solution and deteli be complete, thank you

Comment: @MadritZhaku: No, I'm pretty sure you can finish the argument from here. Remember that $x_k$ and $x_l$ are integers. So what can you say if their distance is less than $1$?

Comment: @StefanH doesn't this imply that Z is not complete?

Comment: @TylerHilton: Why?

Comment: @StefanH because elements are integers and so the min distance is 1.  You say choose $\epsilon < 1$, but no two integers satisfy that.

Comment: @TylerHilton: The question is: What are the Cauchy sequences? And once we know what the Cauchy sequences look like, we can check if they are convergent. We know in a Cauchy sequence there must be an $m$ such that $|x_k-x_l|<1$ for $k,l>m$. We can say something about $x_k$ and $x_l$, and with that I don't mean "They don't exist."

Comment: Ah I see. It means that $x_k$ and $x_l$ are the same eventually.

Comment: @TylerHilton: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Big hint: Show that every Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{Z}$ is eventually constant (take $\epsilon <1$).

Comment: Thank you for your reply but your answer if you can give me the solution and deteli be complete, thank you

Comment: I think the hint I've given is sufficiently complete for you to solve the problem on your own.